# how do I get specific with a big query sql

Tags: mysql, join

This is a simplified version of my relationships:
[image]

And for instance, I can create a "Group" when I do an `INSERT INTO GROUP` , after that an `INSERT INTO taker_in_group` with the ID of the new created group and several other `task_taker_ids`

the table `taker_in_group` and `group` would look like this
[image]

Imagine **I am task_taker with id 3** and I create a new task containing a typ and also asign it to group 1:

[image]

My question is:**How can I get all the tasks that I created and also all the tasks that someone has given to me? (If I were, for instance, another ID)**

Tried a query like this one:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM task t 
  LEFT 
  JOIN task_in_typ tp 
    ON tp.task_id = t.task_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN typ ty 
    ON ty.typ_id = tp.typ_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN assigned_to ag 
    ON ag.task_id = t.task_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN groupe g 
    ON g.group_id = ag.group_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN taker_in_group ttg 
    ON ttg.group_id = g.group_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN task_taker ta 
    ON ta.task_taker_id = ttg.task_taker_id 
 WHERE ta.task_taker_id = 3;
```

The problem is, that query only gives as result all the tasks which are in groups where I am included. If, for example, I create a group without me as member, create a task, asign it to that group and perform the query above, It doesnt show the task I just created. How do I make the query in order to show all the tasks that I created(without me being in the created group) and also the tasks that someone assigned to me? And also without having the same task in several rows

Comment: group is a reserved word, so something about that query doesn't quite ring true

Comment: The images are just examples, in the real db its saved as "groupe"

Comment: Change WHERE to AND... and only select the columns you actually want

Comment: @Strawberry Ok I get all the tasks but the same task in several rows, how do I fix that?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If a task can have many types, then you will get a repeat of the task for each type. If there are multiple groups assigned to a task then you will get a repeat of the task for each group. If there are **both** multiple types to a task and multiple groups to a task then you get multiple rows - of multiple rows. This multiplication of rows expands for each table you join. This is standard behaviour for SQL and "expected".

If you want to inhibit the repetition of information start by limiting the columns and asking for distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      t.task_id, t.title
FROM task t
INNER JOIN task_in_typ tp     ON t.task_id = tp.task_id
INNER JOIN typ ty             ON tp.typ_id = ty.typ_id
INNER JOIN assigned_to ag     ON t.task_id = ag.task_id
INNER JOIN groupe g           ON ag.group_id = g.group_id
INNER JOIN taker_in_group ttg ON g.group_id = ttg.group_id
INNER JOIN task_taker ta      ON ttg.task_taker_id = ta.task_taker_id
WHERE t.task_creator = 'me' -- (i.e. something that evaluates to "me")
OR ta.task_taker_id = 3     -- (assuming 3 equates to "me")
;
```

For each additional column you add to this you may see an increase in the number of rows, and for some information to be repeated.

Notes

1. there is no use using LEFT JOINS if you are going to ignore unmatched rows by demanding certain conditions in the where clause.
2. if a single task will never have multiple types why have the table task_in_typ at all? (Instead just use a foreign key column to type in the task table.)